# Consider for any positive number $a$, how to show that $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x} \sqrt{\ln{x}} \leq 2 + 2x$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Consider for any positive number $x$, how to show that $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x} \sqrt{\ln{x}} \leq 2 + 2x$?

I tried Cauchy inequality and Taylor expansion but still can't figure it out.

Comment: Note that for $x \lt 1, \sqrt {\ln x}$ is not defined, so you should specify $x \ge 1$ and the $a$ in your title should be $x$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks. Forgot that very important point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recalling that for $x \ge 1$, $$\ln x < x$$ and $$\sqrt{x}\le x$$
you have
$$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x} \sqrt{\ln x} < \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x} \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{x} + x \le x+x = 2x < 2x+2$$

For $x < 1$, $\sqrt{ \ln x}$ is not defined.